# Spring Security websocket restricting the paylod len bits value

Tags: spring, spring-security, websocket

According to the [RFC rfc6455 section "5.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-5.2).  Base Framing Protocol" the paylod len (7) bit can be set to:

7 bits -> 1-125 - for the length that is not larger then 125

7+16 bits -> If the payload is set to 126, then we set byte 1 to 126 and extend the length i.e. we interpret the following 16 bits as unsigned integer which gives us 2^16 -> 65535 bytes in length or 64Kb.

7+64 bits -  If the payload is set to 127 then we interpret the next 8 bytes as unsigned integer which is about 2^64 -> or if i am not mistaken that is 1,6 exabyte , one way or die other those are "A LOT" of bytes ....

Now, i have an spring application that uses spring security with websockets. My app is sending only data with length range within thesecond case i.e.7+16 bits. I know for sure that there will be never ever the case when someone will need to open a websocket connection with the payload bit set to 127.

Thus my question is, Is there a way to tell spring that only websocket connections are allowed where the payload bit could be set to the maximum of 126. I.e. if an websocket connection comes in with the payload bit set to 127, it should be closed automatically.

I consider this to be a security feature that could prevent different types of attacks.

Is there an interface in spring that can allow me to do that?

Comment: Such a bonehead restriction will never improve security. Also, it should not be done in Spring layer. Do it in your application layer if you really want to. Apart from it, a constructive answer is "Protect your WebSocket endpoint by either (1) a pair of API key and API secret or (2) an access token. Read [RFC 6749](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749) and [RFC 6750](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6750) for protection based on access tokens.

Comment: well image a user openning a wesockets and uploding garbage. How would you know that this is garbage until you have not completelly received the file. Web socket is application layer thus what do you mean by do it in the Application Layer?   I belive i found how to do it i.e. configuring the WebSocketPolicy and setting setInputBufferSize, i am just not sure if that is the right place for that restriction.

Comment: WebSocket itself is a library/framework layer (I'm the author of [nv-websocket-client](https://github.com/TakahikoKawasaki/nv-websocket-client) library). A callback method (e.g. a method with `@OnMessage` annotation) is the application layer. There exist some mechanisms to set the maximum size of messages, but they cannot be an anti-attack solution. Attackers can still send **small-size** garbage messages to your WebSocket endpoints.

Comment: correct but if my max size is length of 125 bytes then he will try that 3 times and then i will block him and delete his account, while if the size is in exa-bytes i will fail to detect that try at all.